# I need a scalable method for increasing numbers of 2 types of Boolean inputs and outputs in the ratio inputA:inputB:output, 2:1:2, 3:2:3, 4:3:4,

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, boolean-logic

Consider 4 Boolean outputs and 4 Boolean inputs.

```
Input1, Output1 
Input2, Output2 
Input3, Output3 
Input4, Output4
```

They are related such that if Input1=true, then Output1=true. If Input2=true, then Output2=true, etc.

Now consider 3 extra Boolean inputs, that determine whether neighbouring outputs are 'joined together' or not.

```
Output1Output2Joined (true=yes, false=no)
Output2Output3Joined
Output3Output4Joined
```

If two (or more) outputs are 'joined', then a Boolean OR operation needs to work across the now 'joined' Boolean inputs in order to set the value of the now 'joined' Boolean outputs.

Some exemplar scenarios showing outputs below.

```
Output1Output2Joined = false
Output2Output3Joined = false
Output3Output4Joined = false
Input1 = false, Output1 = false
Input2 = false, Output2 = false
Input3 = false, Output3 = false
Input4 = false, Output4 = false
---------------------
Output1Output2Joined = false
Output2Output3Joined = false
Output3Output4Joined = false
Input1 = true, Output1 = true
Input2 = false, Output2 = false
Input3 = false, Output3 = false
Input4 = false, Output4 = false
---------------------
Output1Output2Joined = true
Output2Output3Joined = false
Output3Output4Joined = false
Input1 = true, Output1 = true
Input2 = false, Output2 = true
Input3 = false, Output3 = false
Input4 = false, Output4 = false
---------------------
Output1Output2Joined = false
Output2Output3Joined = false
Output3Output4Joined = true
Input1 = true, Output1 = true
Input2 = false, Output2 = false
Input3 = false, Output3 = true
Input4 = true, Output4 = true
---------------------
Output1Output2Joined = true
Output2Output3Joined = false
Output3Output4Joined = true
Input1 = true, Output1 = true
Input2 = false, Output2 = true
Input3 = false, Output3 = true
Input4 = true, Output4 = true
---------------------
Output1Output2Joined = true
Output2Output3Joined = true
Output3Output4Joined = false
Input1 = true, Output1 = true
Input2 = false, Output2 = true
Input3 = false, Output3 = true
Input4 = false, Output4 = false
```

This is the code I have been using for the scenarios above but I would like a dynamic algorithm so that I can work with 5:4:5, 6:5:6, 7:6:7, inputs/joins/outputs

```
public void changed()
    {
        // Evaluate state of joins
        int joinsState = 0;
        if (getOutput1Output2Joined ) joinsState += 1;
        if (getOutput2Output3Joined ) joinsState += 2;
        if (getOutput3Output4Joined ) joinsState += 4;
        switch (joinsState) {
            case 0: {
                // All joins true therefore perform OR on inputs
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [4];
                inputArray[0] = getInput1();
                inputArray[1] = getInput2();
                inputArray[2] = getInput3();
                inputArray[3] = getInput4();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput1(out);
                setOutput2(out);
                setOutput3(out);
                setOutput4(out);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
           // Output1Output2Joined false, Output2Output3Joined true, Output3Output4Joined true
                setOutput1(getInput1());
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [3];
                inputArray[0] = getInput2();
                inputArray[1] = getInput3();
                inputArray[2] = getInput4();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput2(out);
                setOutput3(out);
                setOutput4(out);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
           // Output1Output2Joined true, Output2Output3Joined false, Output3Output4Joined true
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [2];
                inputArray[0] = getInput1();
                inputArray[1] = getInput2();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput1(out);
                setOutput2(out);
                inputArray[0] = getInput3();
                inputArray[1] = getInput4();
                out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput3(out);
                setOutput4(out);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
          // Output1Output2Joined false, Output2Output3Joined false, Output3Output4Joined true
                setOutput1(getInput1());
                setOutput2(getInput2());
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [2];
                inputArray[0] = getInput3();
                inputArray[1] = getInput4();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput3(out);
                setOutput4(out);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
           // Output1Output2Joined true, Output2Output3Joined true, Output3Output4Joined false
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [3];
                inputArray[0] = getInput1();
                inputArray[1] = getInput2();
                inputArray[2] = getInput3();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput1(out);
                setOutput2(out);
                setOutput3(out);
                setOutput4(getInput4());
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
          // Output1Output2Joined false, Output2Output3Joined true, Output3Output4Joined false
                setOutput1(getInput1());
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [2];
                inputArray[0] = getInput2();
                inputArray[1] = getInput3();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput2(out);
                setOutput3(out);
                setOutput4(getInput4());
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
          // Output1Output2Joined true, Output2Output3Joined false, Output3Output4Joined false
                boolean[] inputArray = new boolean [2];
                inputArray[0] = getInput1();
                inputArray[1] = getInput2();
                boolean out = evaluateInput(inputArray);
                setOutput1(out);
                setOutput2(out);
                setOutput3(getInput3());
                setOutput4(getInput4());
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
         // Output1Output2Joined false, Output2Output3Joined false, Output3Output4Joined false
                setOutput1(getInput1());
                setOutput2(getInput2());
                setOutput3(getInput3());
                setOutput4(getInput4());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean evaluateInput (boolean[] input) {
        boolean pOr = false;
        // Loop through array of input status
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            // If any input true then set output true
            if (input[i]) {
                pOr = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return pOr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm:

1. Copy the input to the output
2. Perform a forward sweep through the joined information. If input[i] is joined with the next input, then perform an OR of output[i] with the next output and store it as the new value for the *next* output (i.e. output[i+1])
3. Perform a backward sweep through the joined information. If input[i+1] is joined with the previous input, then perform an OR of output[i+1] with the previous output and store it as the new value for the *previous* output (i.e. output[i])

Here is example code:

```
public static boolean[] algo(boolean[] inputs, boolean[] joinedWithNext) {
    // Copy input to output
    boolean[] outputs = inputs.clone();

    // Forward sweep
    for (int i = 0; i < joinedWithNext.length; i++) {
        if (joinedWithNext[i]) {
            outputs[i + 1] |= outputs[i];
        }
    }

    // Backward sweep
    for (int i = joinedWithNext.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (joinedWithNext[i]) {
            outputs[i] |= outputs[i + 1];
        }
    }

    return outputs;
}
```

Here is a run of the algorithm with some sample input:

```
// Sample input:
boolean[] inputs = { false, true, false, false };
boolean[] joinedWithNext = { true, true, false }; // One less value

// Perform algorithm
boolean[] outputs = algo(inputs, joinedWithNext);

// Output results
for (boolean b : outputs) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `A join B = True|False` is an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), that is, you safelly can replace every `B` for `A` (important, under that equivalence operation, no other).

Note that, if `A join B = True`, `B join C = False` and `C join A = True`, really, under your `OR` operation is finally `B join C = True`.

That is, your `OR` operation is really a [Transitive closure of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) (a more friendly source could be [this explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transitive-closure-of-a-graph/)).

If you want to be `R join T = false` mandatory you'll fall into contradiction.

Then, you only must to compute that *Transitive closure* for all sentences like:

```
Output1Output2Joined = true
Output2Output3Joined = false
Output3Output4Joined = true
...
```

The previous link has an example code to compute the transitive closure.

The transitive closure will provide to you a way to, given an index (e.g. `Output1`, ...) get the equivalence class (e.g. `Eq38`) and, given the equivalence class (e.g. `Eq38`) get all the orbit (all joined `Output1`, `Output5`, ...).

E.g. using two maps:

```
Map<Integer, String> IndextoEqClass
Map<String, List<Integer>> EqClassIndexes
```

Once you have the transitive closure, for every:

```
Input1 = true, Output1 = true
Input2 = false, Output2 = true
Input3 = false, Output3 = true
...
```

you'll get all outputs under the `OR` operation with

```
Integer currentOutputIndex = ...;
List<Integer> allOROutputIndexes = EqClassIndexes.get(IndextoEqClass.get(currentOutputIndex));
```